# Launching Sway on login with zsh

Tags: arch-linux, zsh, wayland, sway

I set up .bash_profile to exec sway on login, and then ended up switching to zshell as my default shell.

When I log in it just stays it no longer auto launches sway of course. I'm wondering if there is a way to exec sway in Zsh, without trying to launch sway every time I open a terminal, or it I need to configure my terminal to use zsh explicitly and boot with bash?

Comment: Since this question is solved you should [accept](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) an answer by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating .zprofile and adding a small script to it was what I ended up doing.

```
if [[ -z $DISPLAY && $TTY = /dev/tty1 ]]; then
  export MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1
  exec sway
fi
```